# How to switch the locale of the Vuetify v-date-picker component?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vuetify 3.4 and I'm struggling with the [Datepicker locale docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#api)

Given a variable containing the current locale ( english, german, french, ... ) how do I tell Vuetify to switch to e.g. german locale? I tried

```
<v-locale-provider locale="de">
  <v-date-picker></v-date-picker>
</v-locale-provider>
```

but that doesn't seem to be enough. So in the Vuetify settings I also tried to add support for the german locale

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { sv, de } from 'vuetify/locale'
import DateFnsAdapter from '@date-io/date-fns'
import enUS from 'date-fns/locale/en-US'
import svSE from 'date-fns/locale/sv'
import deGer from 'date-fns/locale/de'

export const vuetify = createVuetify({
  locale: {
    messages: { sv, de },
  },
  date: {
    adapter: DateFnsAdapter,
    locale: {
      en: enUS,
      sv: svSE,
      de: deGer,
    },
  },
})
```

But I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "date-fns/locale/de". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

[Reproduction example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Sidenote: I don't need to use a custom adapter. All I want to do is to pass my locales to the `v-locale-provider`. So I tried no configuration `export const vuetify = createVuetify()` but this doesn't seem to work, when I try to pass `fr` or `de` I get the warning

> Vuetify: Translation key "$vuetify.datePicker.title" not found in "de", trying fallback locale

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the import map, it works just fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Although I want to use the default settings, I created a new issue https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/18777

Comment: For the default settings you don't need a new adapter - use the Vuetify default one.

Comment: yes, thought so. how would you fix this? https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqVUc1OwzAMfpUoF0BaEqHtgKZtGi/BhXDoWk8Emh85WRma+u64aQ5d4TBusf392F9eLzxirboTJHP8lh+Rr7mxwWNiF1YjVAlexhnr2RG9ZXcFe6eddnDO0Nq7mFgZsO018f5BO77INs8hSEKRxyaBDS2BdtoxtulEFUJ+5qL1ddWCCOg70wCysd5qfkTNCywDG1IQwdSfgLuNuq6LGnVncqMl9UfPjZrsQouO5wtbBYrDO1r2MhB0GUTN1yx3hh5dM9Sav6cU4lqpunFEa6A1HUoHSblg1Z5gCk8uGQui8Xa/lEu5Uo2JadqWEK04oP+KgCSi+WJiM0R5g1VBksNKPo4OpSXa6hAHiz+l1RjSvxyW8km15lCoyrgGztLO1RVd0wEKBJoj0A/elteMNs1sNvqV2+Dea9fzfsEzjb41B8LffgD0LgFZ

Comment: I can't fix the bug - the Vuetify team can. But in the mean time you can use the Date.IO adapter instead, as shown in the documentation that you pointed above.